# Code formatter like nb_black for google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, pep8, python-black

I know that for jupyter notebooks and jupyter lab, there are available code formatter extensions such as `nb_black`or `blackcellmagic`. However when I installed them, it doesn't seem to work on google colab.

Do you know if there are any native option in colab or an extension that formats code (pep8 compliant)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of now (April 2023) the top answer - `black` - works without kernel restarts.

So

```
# run once
!pip install black[jupyter] --quiet
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive")
...
# run many times
!black /content/drive/MyDrive/'Colab Notebooks'/'HiringBias.ipynb'
```

plus page refreshing gives

```
reformatted /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/HiringBias.ipynb
All done! ✨  ✨
1 file reformatted.
```

:-)

Answer (score 14):

I don't think there's an extension directly in Colab.

What you could do, though, is to download your notebook, run

```
pip install -U nbqa
nbqa black notebook.ipynb
```

and then reupload your (now formatted) notebook to Colab

---

disclaimer: I'm the author of [nbQA](https://github.com/nbQA-dev/nbQA)

---

UPDATE: as of version 21.8b0, `black` runs directly on notebooks, no third-party tool required

Answer (score 12):

I have tried everything, none of the JupyterLab/Notebook backend hack methods seem to work as of February 2022. However, until later here is a relatively simple workaround:

[Run only once, at startup]

- Connect to your `drive`

  `from google.colab import drive`
  `drive.mount("/content/drive")`
- Install `black` for `jupyter`

  `!pip install black[jupyter]`
- Restart kernel

[Then]

- Place your `.ipynb` file somewhere on your drive
- Anytime you want format your code run:
  `!black /content/drive/MyDrive/YOUR_PATH/YOUR_NOTEBOOK.ipynb`
- **Don't** save your notebook, hit `F5` to refresh the page
- Voila!
- **Now save!**

Comment: +1 It was great. I needed slight modification (`!black '/content/drive/MyDrive/YOUR_PATH/YOUR_NOTEBOOK.ipynb'`)  as my path contained a folder that had a space in its name.