# How to use jupyter nbextension "code prettify" in google colab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have been using jupyter notebook for a long time. Recently I am using google colab for some experimentation. One thing I always do in jupyter notebook is format the code using "code prettify" extension.

Is there a way to use this extension in google colab?

I would greatly appreciate the suggestions.

References

- https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/code_prettify/README_code_prettify.html

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/63076002/61109 which also has no answer