# Code fomatting in Google Colab like autopep8 or black for Jupyter

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I just use Google Colab for research and to learn machine learning, but there is one thing I still don't know how to do. How to format code in Google Colab? In this case I mean like `autopep8` or `black` on Jupyter notebooks, I always mess with my code, for example:

```py
x=1.223333433
print("%3f"%x)
```

will be

```py
x = 1.223333433
print("%3f" % x)
```

So a code formatter would be awesome, thanks a lot.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/63076002/61109 (which also does no have an answer)

Comment: There is an answer but might not be what you / we expect ;)

Comment: I've posted a workaround now.

Comment: Use `black[jupyter]` directly on Google Colab, possible since recently, as explaind here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63076002/code-formatter-like-nb-black-for-google-colab/76030301#76030301